# unusual time lag in typing and copy pasting

Tags: front-end, copy-as

I have been experiencing a time lag in typing and copy-pasting on Mathematica files. I have checked that this is not the case with any other WYSIWYG interface on my computer. For example, it takes 3-6 seconds for the text to appear after ctrl+v. And since this is only happening with Mathematica, I am not sure what's the problem. I even re-installed the latest version 11.1 and unchecked syntax coloring but it hasn't helped. Has anyone experienced same kind of typing/copy-pasting time lag? I didn't find similar issues online.

Comment: Is it slower than copy/paste of the same code, from the same files, but using older versions?

Comment: I see that you used the webmathematica and mathematica online tags. Is the problem with the desktop mathematica version, or the online one?

Comment: Daniel, yes, same code from the same file and same version. MarcoB, I really didn't know what tags to use and I couldn't find anything related to time lags. This is the desktop version.

Comment: This might be operating system dependent. What are you using?

Comment: Mikado, you might be right. I am using Windows 10 on a Mac 2012. It has worked well for me besides Mathematica.

Comment: but in my observation mathematica becomes slow when I run MS Word at the same time. It also slows down my FireFox. Close Word, everthing works fine for me. I have no other solution for the underlying issue, though.

Comment: I had a similar problem with very slow typing in Mathematica for Windows running on a Citrix server. My solution was to switch to Mathematica running via X11 on a linux server. Is your Mathematica installed directly on a disk connected to the machine you are running it on?

Comment: 1) Does the time it takes to paste depend on the length/type of what you copied? 2) Did you monitor the processes (similar to htop in Linux, e.g.) to see if either RAM or CPU was blowing up?